# Using WCF Service to access SQL Server in Entity Framework -- Why does it seem like it's using Integrated Security?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, connection-string, service-reference

**Quick Background**
I received code from a third party (contracted software) that I have to move onto my servers. When I run the code using their connections and service references, everything works well. When I debug locally, everything works well. My problem only occurs when I try to run the application/service(s) after I move them onto my server.

The services (or their respective references) are at the heart of what's causing the issues. I created a test client to try to debug the services, and it's accessing the service, but erroring when it tries to connect to the SQL Server inside the service. The code appears to use the Entity Framework which I am admittedly not familiar with yet.

**Errors/Issues**
When I use my test client to call a function inside the service reference, it errors out when it tries to connect to my SQL database:

```
using (ApplicationDefinitionDBEntities appDefDb = new ApplicationDefinitionDBEntities()) //ERROR
```

Here's the error I receive (domain and server names have been made generic):

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'MYDOMAIN\APPSERVERNAME$'.

I found the `app.config` that is referenced by the `.edmx` file (`ApplicationDefinitionDB.edmx`) and its accompanying files. Here is the connection string (made generic):

```
<add name="ApplicationDefinitionDBEntities"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.ApplicationDefinitionDB.csdl|res://*/Data.ApplicationDefinitionDB.ssdl|res://*/Data.ApplicationDefinitionDB.msl;
     provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
     provider connection string=&quot;data source=MYDBSERVERNAME;initial catalog=myDBcatalog;
     User ID=myUserID;Password=myPassword;integrated security=false;
     multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

There is also an old connection string that the third party used which had integrated security set to true and reference `SQLExpress`, but I commented it out.

Note that I am specifying integrated security to be false (I know it's by default but I wanted to be explicit), and also supplying a username and password to the SQL Server. So why is the error message in the service ref test client saying that it's trying to connect using `DOMAIN\APPSERVER$` as though it's using integrated security?

I am using IIS to host my app and SQL Server for database work. I think I have updated and re-generated all Entity Framework stuff for the database reference, but I could be missing something. Can anyone suggest anything that I may be missing to make sure the service reference uses the connection string supplied in it, and NOT the app server domain login? Thanks!

Comment: Is the sqlserver installed on the server where you have your service?

Comment: No, the sql server is on its own server. For example, the application (and the service) is on `AAP` (app server) and the database is on `ADB` (database server). So in the error message, it's showing the `AAP` domain/servername when it's trying to connect to `ADB`.

Comment: Perhaps one of the accepted answers of this [asp forum thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1731963.aspx/1) can help you?

Comment: Thanks but it seems like those answers are providing some sort of workarounds to add the app server as a user on the database server or to edit active directory, which isn't feasible for me since I'll be moving this to several other servers so I just want to be able to edit a connection string and be done with it. I'm able to log in to SQL server from the app server with the username and password provided in the connection string, so I'm trying to figure out why the service isn't using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that connection string conflicted with one above the project level of the service. The project that housed the service uses Silverlight, so I thought the `ClientConfig` files were the only other configs being used, but there was another one hiding in the project that I published. When I rooted around in that `web.config` file, I found that there was a connection string with `Integrated Security` turned on. Once I turned that off it worked fine. That's annoying.